# user interface in .net 4.5 and windows presentation foundation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am still trying to get my head around wpf ui creation.  I have created a user control which has a expander, dockpanel and two comboboxes in the dockpanel with equal width hardcoded in xaml.  It looks good during the design time and in runtime as long as the expander widths is unchanged.  When the expander header is changed to a longer text the dockpanel streches and the two comboxes remain the same size. They are docked to the right hence there is a lot of gap between two comboxes.

My question, is there a way to equally space the two comboboxes in the dockpanel.

Code:

```
<DockPanel Height="Auto" 
           DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="lhsInput" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" 
           LastChildFill="False">
    <ComboBox Height="23" Name="cboLHSItem"
              Width="84" FontWeight="Normal" 
              Margin="1,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Tahoma" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
              Name="cboLHSValues" Width="79" FontWeight="Normal" 
              IsEditable="False" Margin="0,0,1,0" FontFamily="Tahoma" 
              Foreground="Black" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Can you not use `Grid`?

Comment: I dont see why not, Will the comboboxes stretch if a grid is used instead of dockpanel?

Comment: Maga, could not figure out what you have edited. Iam fairly new to stackoverflow still figuring out how everything works. When I use the grid it works. Thanks. A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Grid` instead of `DockPanel`, Sample code below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Height="23" Name="cboLHSItem"
          MinWidth="79"
          Grid.Column="0"
          FontWeight="Normal" 
          Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Tahoma" />

    <ComboBox Height="23" MinWidth="79"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Name="cboLHSValues" FontWeight="Normal" 
          IsEditable="False" FontFamily="Tahoma" 
          Foreground="Black" />
</Grid>
```

`DockPanel` may be providing the required Width for its Child elements. However, with `Grid` and its `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` you can specify whether you want "Auto" Width/Height or you want to use whatever is available for Width/Height. The above code specifies to use Whatever width available for the Child element by setting `Width` to `*` in `ColumnDefinition`.

**UPDATE**

To Understand how different Panels of WPF work, refer to MSDN page: [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)